# Compensation for printed ad error in annual directory

Tags: fonts, error

My business partner and I paid for advertising in a neighborhood directory that is published annually. The designer send us a proof of the ad which we approved. After the directory was published, an error in the font of our ad was noticed.

The error happened for the initial letters of our first names (the name of our business!). So the initial letters are K's and they look small in comparison with the rest of our name and all of the wording below our name (apparently the font messed up and didn't print the curved parts with the K's). The rest of the half page ad was done as per the proof.

Basically, we approved an ad (the proof looked great) but something happened in production (the font issue) that messed up our names (and it is in 2 different places - the ad and on the divider tab that goes with our ad). The items cannot be reprinted (our ad is one of many in addition to the names and addresses of all in the neighborhood). This directory is only printed annually so now the error remains all year.

The company is asking what remedy we are asking for. Should we get all of our money back? Should we ask for half of it? Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: I suggest All your money back plus reparations for permanently damaging the professionalism of your brand. The mistake caused embarrassment, made you look bad and hurt your image in the eyes of your customers. They caused you damages with their error which should have been avoided with usual print proof procedures.

Answer (score 2):

Certainly a *complete* refund seeing how they *completely* messed up the job. A proof is a proof. If the end result was not identical to the proof then they failed 100%.

I'd suggest a reasonable amount of fiscal compensation, but in the real world, from a small business, I cannot see it happening.

Free advertising for a period going forwards might be useful...if you trust them to get it right next time! (Questionable!)